Why does $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{Ring}}(\mathbb{Z}[T,T^{-1}],H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X))=H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)^\times$
Let $X$ be a scheme. Why does $\operatorname{Hom}_{\text{Ring}}(\mathbb{Z}[T,T^{-1}],H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X))=H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)^\times$? I know any ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[T] \to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is determined by where you send $T$, yet I don't see how this implies the above equality. Thank you for any help!

A ring homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Z}[T, T^{-1}]$ is similarly determined by where you send $T$ and where you send $T^{-1}$. Moreover, by definition, the two must be inverse to each other. Which means...?

This has nothing to do with $H^0(X, {\cal O}_X)$ specifically; just note that $\mathbb{Z}[T, T^{-1}] = \mathbb{Z}[X, Y]/(XY - 1)$ (by definition).

@QiaochuYuan thank you, I don’t know how I missed this since it is very obvious.
